# How can I show percentages of each level in a stacked ggplot Geom_bar with a factor variable on each axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am trying to create a horizontal stacked bar chart with the percentage of each level shown. I can do it when I only have one bar, but when I have a fact9r variable as the x axis too, the percentages come out as percentages of the total number rather than percentages of each level (i.e. the percentages on each bar should add to 100 rather than the percentages in the whole chart).

This is an example of my

`data <- data.frame( Variable1 = factor(c( 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ), levels = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') ), Variable2 = factor( c( "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), levels = c("Yes", "No")))`

And my code to plot it currently looks like this:

```
`ggplot(data, aes(x = Variable2, fill = Variable1)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(
       aes(label = paste0(round(after_stat(count / sum(count)) * 100), "%")),
       stat = "count",
       size = 3,
       hjust = 0.7,
       position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
     )   `
```

I have tried making percentages with this:

```
`percentages <- data %>%
  group_by(Variable1, Variable2) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  group_by(Variable1) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = (Count / sum(Count)) * 100)`
```

and displaying them with as geom_text but i cannot get it to work. Can anyone help? I have tried all the answers on here and cant get them to work with my data.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your first approach is that you did your computation not account for the grouping by `Variable2`. While that could be fixed the easier approach would be to compute the percentages outside of `ggplot` as you tried in your second approach.

Not sure why this second approach did not work for you (except that you have chosen the wrong grouping variable when computing the percentages). But here is one working approach:

```
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

percentages <- data %>%
  count(Variable2, Variable1, name = "Count") %>%
  group_by(Variable2) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = Count / sum(Count))

ggplot(data, aes(y = Variable2, fill = Variable1)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(
    data = percentages,
    aes(x = Count, label = scales::percent(Percentage)),
    size = 3,
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is one approach to add the total counts on the right of the bars:

```
ggplot(data, aes(y = Variable2)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Variable1), position = "fill") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(paste0("N = ", count)), group = 1),
    stat = "count", hjust = -.05,
    position = position_fill()
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(
    data = percentages,
    aes(x = Count, label = scales::percent(Percentage), group = Variable1),
    size = 3,
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1, .25), 
    labels = scales::percent,
    expand = expansion(add = c(0, .2))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked great - not sure how i managed to get it the wrong way round!

Comment: Is there a way of adding the Total N to the end of the bar?

Comment: See my edit for one approach.